# Android Alert manager delete

Tags: android, alert

I have set an alert manager for every event created by user. If any user delete the event after that, I want to delete the alert manager set for the specific event. How to delete any specific alert programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

> I have set an alert manager for every event created by user.

I am going to assume that you really mean that you have set an alarm with `AlarmManager`.

> How to delete any specific alert programmatically?

Call `cancel()` on `AlarmManager` with a `PendingIntent` for an equivalent `Intent`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist/tree/master/19-Alarm/LunchList) that demonstrates this (see OnBootReceiver.java).

Comment: The code is not matching with my requirement. There may be multiple alert created by AlertManager at any certain time, each one for different events created by user. So I want to delete any specific alert when the specific event deleted. How to do it?

Comment: @dalandroid: You do it exactly the way I wrote above.